# Hadoop : Splitting the Text box class content based on composite delimiter

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a file that contains compressed data seperated by composite delimiter(~~#&#&#~~)
I am trying to create a mapper to read records in the file and process them.

I have written a Mapper class such as

In the Split loop I am printing first 20 character for each splitted record but am not seeing the data as expected. I guess Split is not working on it.

Can some one help.

I have been trying number of conversion techniques between Text and String or Text and BytesWritable...but nothing seems to work.

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter; 
public class DeSerializeMapper extends MapReduceBase 
implements Mapper 
{ 
   public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
   { 
       String allRec = value.toString(); 
       for (String recStr : allRec.split("~~#&#&#~~")) 
       { 
           try 
           { 
               System.out.println("DEBUG ::::::::::::::::::::::::::Before calling SubstringIn : " + recStr.substring(0,20)); 
               output.collect(new Text(recStr), new Text(getOutputString(recStr))); 
           }catch(Exception e){ 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                throw new IOException("Failed in map", e); 
           } 
       } 
   }

   public static String getOutputString(String recStr) throws Exception 
   {
       try {
                  dosomething(); 
                  return (lineBuffer); 
       } catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            throw new Exception("Failed in readFile", e); 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your S.O.P statements wont appear on console when added in MR code. They will be appended to the MR job system logs.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, your `System.out.println()` statements wont appear on console when added in MR code. They will be appended to the MR job system logs.

To see the `System.out.println()` statements, visit the JobTracker page (mostly running on port 50030), go to the specific MR job that you have executed and then check the map task logs. You will find the `System.out.println()`statements under **stdout logs** (if any).

Comment: Ankur that is good to know. But my question is why is split not working. Or is something there that I have missed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Split is not working'. Can you please elaborate?